# SEO impact of setting job listing post publish date to always be the current date?

Tags: seo, wordpress

A client wants to keep one of their permanent job listing posts (on a WordPress-based site) in good SEO standing and is afraid that a post date going back to 2015 will negatively impact the SEO of this job listing post. They're curious if they could have the post automatically update the publish date periodically. I haven't come across an easy way to have the site do that periodically, but I did find [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97227/changing-the-post-date-and-time-with-function) about updating a post's date to the current date/time.

My concern is that Google will flag the post as spam because the post date keeps changing (even if I found a way to automatically update periodically), or that it will otherwise negatively affect SEO. What would the potential impact be on SEO for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to articles like this: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-changing-article-dates/225789/, you'll clearly see that changing the publish date of a post can be very risky for your site's SEO, potentially resulting in your entire site getting dates removed in search results.

I'd push back on the client and tell them it would hurt their SEO to do something like that.

Comment: Would they be ok to just update the publish date once or twice a year in that case? That way it's not too frequent to look suspicious.

Comment: Black, white and gray. What you are asking is moving through the gray path of SEO which  I'll never do with any of my clients. It's not worth.